# Cones and homeomorphisms

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ is a topological space, we define a relation $\sim$ in $X\times [0,1]$ to be $(x,s)\sim (y,t)$ if $(x,s)=(y,t)$ or $t=s=1$. The cone of $X$ is the quotient space $X/\sim$. I'll denote it as $CX$.

Now, if $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, we define the geometric cone $X$ to be the subset $GX\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ formed by the union of all segments from $(0,1)$ to every point of $X\times\{0\}$. Namely the union off all $l_x=\{t(0,1)+(1-t)(x,0):t\in [0,1]\}.$

Finally, let $X=\{1/n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and $Y=X\cup\{0\}$.

I want to show that $CY\cong GY$, but $CX$ is not homeomorphic to $GX$.

Here are my two questions:

1) I wish to show that $CY\cong GY$ without using anything of compactness. I define $f:Y\times I\to GY$ by $f(y,t)=t(0,1)+(1-t)(y,0)$. In order to show that $f$ is quotient, I want to show it is closed. Would you have any hint to do this? Or rather you'd always use the compactness of $Y\times I$ (this way $f$ is clearly closed)?

2) I have no idea to show $CX$ is not homeomorphic to $GX$. Any hint you can provide would be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that $X\times1$ does not have countable neighborhood base in the cone $CX$, in contrast to $GX$ being first-countable (as a subspace of the first-countable $\Bbb R^2$).

Assume that $(U_n)_n$ is countable neighborhood base of the apex $a=X\times\{1\}$ and that all $U_n$ are open. Then each $U_n$ is the image of a unique set $U'_n\subset X\times I$, which is open and contains $X\times\{1\}$. We can write $U'_n$ as a disjoint union of the sets $U^k_n = U'_n\cap\left\{\frac1k\right\}\times I$. Can you construct an open set $V$ containing $X\times\{1\}$ which does not contain any of the sets $U'_n$. Hint: Think of [Cantor's diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument).

Comment: in order to $V$ does not contain $U'_n$, we need that $V$ does not contain $U_n'\cap (\{1/k\}\times I)$ for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$, right? How about if we pick some open $V^k_n\subseteq \{1/k\}\times I$ such that $V^k_n$ does not contain $U^k_n$ and then $V_n=\cup V^k_n$ and $V=\cup V_n$? Would this work?

Comment: @TRmate: You should pick $V_n$ such that it does not contain $U^n_n$. Then $V=\bigcup V_n$ does not contain any $U_n$.

Comment: well, the truth is I don't really understand. If you say that, I could just pick $V_n$ as $U_n'\cap (\{1/(n+1)\}\times I)$. It surely does not contain $U_n^n$. Does it work, though?

Comment: @TRmate: I forgot to say that $V_n$ is a neighborhood of $\left(\frac1n,1\right)$ in $\left\{\frac1n\right\}\times I$, and $V$ is the disjoint union of the $V_n$. Now if $V$ contained any $U'_m$, then $V_m$ would contain $U_m^m$ which it does not, by construction.